# HTML, JS: positioning an element is inaccurate

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

my aim is to put a dropdown list into a cell.

```
var obj = document.getElementById('dropdown');
var coords = { x: 0, y: 0 };
var element = this;
while (element)
{
 coords.x += element.offsetLeft;
 coords.y += element.offsetTop;
 element = element.offsetParent;
}
obj.style.left = coords.x+'px';
obj.style.top = coords.y+'px';
```

however, this cant find the accurate position. How to fix it?

Comment: Why do absolute positioning when you can just inject the dropdown inside the cell?

Comment: because it must be removed from cell then... easier to positioning

Comment: So? It's just as easy to prune a DOM tree branch as it is to graft it on in the first place. inserting/removing is a SINGLE dom call, compared to your loop and calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach should work perfectly, maybe something else is messing up the positioning?

If you have an element with style `position: relative`, elements that are added to that element with style `position: absolute` with still be relative to that element. If you try to determine the position of an element just by looking at the offset and then walking upwards (disregarding any relatively positioned elements) you wont get the right values. You should find the closest common element with relative positioning and get the offset up to that element.